# Aggregation + sorting +pagination in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do an aggregation + sorting + pagination in one of the indexes.

I learned about internal functionality of Elastic search,

I have 5 total shards, it will sort the individual shards and fetch the result, by default each shard will return  in 10 records. Then the 50 records are sorted again and it will fetch the top 10 record since by default size is 10.

ouput:

The aggregated results are returned in separate field named as "aggregations".In order to do pagination in this aggregated data,size and from are not working.

So tired of doing termBuilder.size(500), now the logic was differs as per this link (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

It leads to inaccuracy of data.

Can any one suggest me how to deal with aggregation + pagination.

Answer (score 17):

In elasticsearch, it's not possible to paginate an aggregation. The query will not give accurate results if size is specified. So, the only way to do sorting and pagination is to give size 0 and return all the documents and then, get the required results by accumulating all the results in a list for further operation.

Comment: Actually, pagination is possible and is in fact a basic part of ES: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html However, I don't know that it's possible during aggregation.

Comment: the pagination is only possible for hits using from and size. But for aggregation, there is no such way to paginate with accurate results. The size in aggregation if specified doesn't give accurate results.

Comment: Ah, I see -- so it's only impossible during aggregation? Odd that the size won't give you accurate results when you're aggregating; I wonder why that is. I mean, it has the list of results; I wonder why it can't infer its size or paginate on it.

Comment: it's explained here on size. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: I think I'm understanding more -- are you saying it's just the aggregation that you can't paginate, or the entire set of documents can't be paginated when an aggregation is present?

Comment: Aggregation can't be used for pagination but the entire set of documents can be paginated using the hits that can be generated from the top query using from and size.

Comment: aggregation itself can not be paginated as written before. However you can paginated aggregated results. 

For example, let's assume you have top hit aggregation, then you can get top five results or second best five results. That's possible because aggregation itself considered as a query. 

Hope this information will help to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 16):

Yes it is possible pagination + sorting + searching elasticsearch [Open link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html). Elasticsearch supports **Bucket Sort Aggregation** in in v6.X and later. This **bucket_sort** uses all records in terms/date_histogram bucket and apply over that. So for this case we have to keep bucket size big enough or more than bucket records so that it keep all possible records in bucket. Example as follows...

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "aggs1": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "field_name.keyword",
                // We can do sort here also
                "size": 1000000  // Keep this size big integer. This keep all possible result in bucket
            },
            "aggs": {
                "bucket_sort": {
                    "bucket_sort": {                                 
                        "sort": [{
                            "_key": {
                                "order": "asc"
                            }
                        }],
                        // This "from" and "size" use above terms bucket size. it applies over available bucket data [This one give actual result]
                        // Bellow is standard pagination as we do
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

Comment: bucket_sort only work for the same `aggs` Aggregation . If you have multi level `aggs` ,it can't work.

Comment: great! thank you. It's work for me with 2 level aggs

Comment: Is there a notable performance cost associated with setting the size so high?

Answer (score 13):

I think `Composite Aggregation` might solve your problem, as it allows pagination within aggregated results.

Please refer to [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html)

Comment: composite aggregation works only with term, date histogram and histogram aggregation. However the value sources can't be sub aggregated. But it do solve the problem to a large extent.

Comment: Just an additional note on this: I'm using Composite Aggregation on keyword-based terms (indexed as keywords rather than terms) and it's working quite nicely

Comment: Note: composite aggregation doesn't allow arbitrary sort order like term aggregation does (e.g. order by doc count, sub-aggregation or multiple criteria).

Answer (score 12):

ElasticSearch supports `Bucket Sort Aggregation` in v6.1 and later. It allows "sort", "size" and "from" parameters within aggregated results.

Please refer to [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html)

Comment: Note: Bucket Sort aggregation only applies to buckets already returned from the parent aggregation, not the whole set.

Answer (score 2):

Paging aggregation results is supported using `partition`. This section in the official docs is very helpful.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "expired_sessions": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "account_id",
            "include": {
               "partition": 0,
               "num_partitions": 20
            },
            "size": 10000,
            "order": {
               "last_access": "asc"
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "last_access": {
               "max": {
                  "field": "access_date"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But, you won't be able to do global sorting using pagination. You can only get sorted results in each partition.

Comment: In partition, I can not decide the number of records per partition. ES divides equally number of records in each partition. for ex. an index has 950 records and I want to get the page with 1000 records, to achieve this I have to create 10 partitions. But ES divides 95 records to each partition.

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch, there is no accurate solution for it. [You may use filtering with partition options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions) but applied partitioner **can break your sorted result**. ES performs partition operation over a given field and **returns buckets from requested partition**. So your result end up with partition ordered.*(you need to make subsequent request with other partition number to gather data from all partitions.)*

My suggestion is give a higher size value for each term as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a work around. Suppose you want to show 10 records per page in ascending order of a field f1, then store the last value of that field for each page(10th, 20th ...) and use greater than and sort in the search query.

Answer (score -1):

If someone also struggle with the same problem here is a PHP and Elastica (http://elastica.io/) solution that works for me.

```
function addAggregationFields($oAgg){
    $oAggField = new Stats('costs');
    $oAggField->setField('costs');
    $oAgg->addAggregation($oAggField);
    return $oAgg;
}
function addAggregationFilters($oAggFilter){
    $oFilters = new \Elastica\Query\Terms();
    $oFilters->setTerms("user_id", [3,7]);
    $oAggFilter->setFilter($oFilters);
    return $oAggFilter;
}


$iItemsInPage = 100;
$iPage        = 0;
$sGoupBy = "created_date";

$oStore = new Store();
$oStore->setConfiguration(new SearchConfiguration());
$oIndex = $oStore->getIndex("report_*");

$oAggFilter = new Filter('cardinality');
$oAggFilter = addAggregationFilters($oAggFilter);

$oAgg = new Cardinality('cardinality');
$oAgg->setField($sGoupBy);
$oAggFilter->addAggregation($oAgg);

$oCardinalityQuery = new Query();
$oCardinalityQuery->setSize(0);
$oCardinalityQuery->addAggregation($oAggFilter);
$resultSet = $oIndex->search($oCardinalityQuery)->getAggregations();

if(isset($resultSet['cardinality'])) {
    $iCardinality = $resultSet['cardinality']['cardinality']['value'];
    if(0 != $resultSet['cardinality']['cardinality']['value']) {
        $iPages = ceil($iCardinality / $iItemsInPage);
    } else {
        $iPages = 1;
    }
}

$oAggFilter = new Filter('aggregation_result');
$oAggFilter = addAggregationFilters($oAggFilter);

$oAgg = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Terms('terms');
$oAgg->setField($sGoupBy);
$oAgg->setParam("include", array("partition" => $iPage, "num_partitions" => $iPages));
$oAgg->setOrder('costs.sum', 'desc');

$oAgg->setSize($iItemsInPage);
$oAgg = $this->addAggregationFields($oAgg);
$oAggFilter->addAggregation($oAgg);

$oQuery = new Query();
$oQuery->addAggregation($oAggFilter);
$oQuery->setSize(0);

$resultSet = $oIndex->search($oQuery)->getAggregations();
```

The Process is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351245/2923963