# ElasticSearch - Aggregation/Group by: sorting and pagging

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, indexing, nosql

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch (2.4) aggregation to group by "productId" on more then one index using that query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "min_score": 0.15,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match_phrase_prefix": {
                "keywords.family": {
                  "query": "low fat milk",
                  "fuzziness": 0.7,
                  "boost": 5
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_0": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "productId",
        "size": 50

      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_tag_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1) I want to sort by _score so I've tried using

```
"order": {"_score": "desc"}
```

which return

```
"type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
"reason": "Invalid term-aggregator order path [_score]. Unknown aggregation [_score]"
```

2) Also, I'm trying to use paging - the "size" key actually working but "from" won't

**UPDATE - example result with aggregation **

```
{
  "took": 5108,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 105,
    "successful": 105,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 9963,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_0": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 69,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 9779,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 98761,
          "doc_count": 36,
          "top_tag_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 36,
              "max_score": 0.36901662,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "retailer-1",
                  "_type": "product",
                  "_id": "1409421",
                  "_score": 0.36901662,
                  "_source": {
                    "productId": 98761
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 107459,
          "doc_count": 36,
          "top_tag_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 36,
              "max_score": 0.42744976,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "retailer-2",
                  "_type": "product",
                  "_id": "1402563",
                  "_score": 0.42744976,
                  "_source": {
                    "productId": 107459
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: You are using "order" in `terms` aggregation , which is not allowed. On what documents do you want to apply sorting. Can you provide sample output ?

Comment: @Richa , due to here is do allowed 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order

Comment: I meant "order by _score" .. Sorry for incomplete comment. Reiterating my question.  On what documents do you want to apply sorting. Can you provide sample output ?

Comment: @Richa, example result with aggregation added, hope that what you have asked to

Comment: You mean you want to order your top hits in decreasing order of score. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Richa, you right, but I'm also want to paging the result, the paging is the most important for me.

Comment: I have given a query in answer. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query

```
{
 "from": 0,
 "size": 0,
 "query": {
 "filtered": {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "keywords.family": {
              "query": "low fat milk",
              "fuzziness": 0.7,
              "boost": 5
            }
               }
             }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
   },
  "aggs": {
  "group_by_0": {
    "terms": {
    "field": "productId",
    "size": 50

  },
     "aggs": {
        "top_tag_hits": {
           "top_hits": {
              "size": 1,
              "sort": [
                 {
                    "_score": {
                       "order": "desc"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

This will order top hits in decreasing order of score. For pagination on aggregation buckets, that is not possible as of now. Might get this feature in  newer versions.

Comment: tried it, it still sorted randomly, could you try help with the paging instead? thanks

Comment: `order` was set to `asc` in answer. have updated it.

Comment: Where do you want to apply paging. In top hits you are fetching only one document. `paging` does not make any sense there. And in Query data as well we have set `size=0`.

Comment: I changed order to desc, still randomly ..
I want to apply paging on the buckets array...

Comment: You mean aggregation on buckets. that's not possible I guess Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776582/aggregation-sorting-pagination-in-elastic-search

Comment: so you are saying there is no possible doing any of this problem?

Comment: just edit your answer so there is no possible doing it, with the sources, and I'll accept your answer so someone else will get here will know..

Comment: Edited my answer.