# How to add paging in Elasticsearch's aggregation？

Tags: elasticsearch, paging, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an elasticsearch request as below：

```
{
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "group_by_state":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"poi_id"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "sum(price)":{
                    "sum":{
                        "field":"price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add paging in this requst, just like

```
select poi_id, sum(price) from table group by poi_id limit 0,2
```

I've searched a lot, and found a link about it:https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915.

But still I didn't get the implementation method.

Is there any way to implement it by Elasticsearch itself but not my application?

Answer (score 3):

I am working through a solution for paging aggregation results currently. What you want to use is `partition`. This section in the official docs is very helpful.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions

To adapt your example, the `terms` setting would be updated as follows.

```
{
    "size":0,
    "aggs":{
        "group_by_state":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"poi_id",
                "include": {
                    "partition": 0,
                    "num_of_partitions": 100
                },
                "size": 10000
            },
            "aggs":{
                "sum(price)":{
                    "sum":{
                        "field":"price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will group your results into 100 partitions (`num_of_partitions`), with a max size of 10k results in each (`size`), and retrieve the first such partition (`partition: 0`)

If you have more than 10k unique values for the field you are aggregating on (and want to return all values) you will want to increase the `size` value or potentially compute `size` and `num_of_partitions` dynamically based on the cardinality of your field.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation

You might also want to use the `show_term_doc_count_error` setting to make sure your aggregation is returning accurate counts. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_per_bucket_document_count_error

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but just discovered ['composite'](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) aggregations in v6.3+. These allow:  
1. A more 'Sql like' grouping  
2. Pagination by use of the 'after_key'.  
Saved our day, hope it will help others too.

Example, getting number of hits per hour between 2 dates, grouped on 5 fields:

```
GET myindex-idx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"docType": "myDOcType"}}, 
        {"range": {
          "@date": {"gte": "2019-06-19T21:00:00", "lt": "2019-06-19T22:00:00"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "mybuckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 100, 
        "sources": [
          {"@date": {
            "date_histogram": {
              "field": "@date", 
              "interval": "hour", 
              "format": "date_hour"}
            }
          }, 
          {"field_1": {"terms": {"field": "field_1"}}}, 
          {"field_2": {"terms": {"field": "field_2"}}}, 
          {"field_3": {"terms": {"field": "field_3"}}}, 
          {"field_4": {"terms": {"field": "field_4"}}}, 
          {"field_5": {"terms": {"field": "field_5"}}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
{
  "took": 255,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 80,
    "successful": 80,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 46989,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "mybuckets": {
      "after_key": {
        "@date": "2019-06-19T21",
        "field_1": 262,
        "field_2": 347,
        "field_3": 945,
        "field_4": 2258,
        "field_5": 0
      },
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": {
            "@date": "2019-06-19T21",
            "field_1": 56,
            "field_2": 106,
            "field_3": 13224,
            "field_4": 46239,
            "field_5": 0
          },
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": {
            "@date": "2019-06-19T21",
            "field_1": 56,
            "field_2": 106,
            "field_3": 32338,
            "field_4": 76919,
            "field_5": 0
          },
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        ....
```

Following paging query issued like this, using the 'after_key object in the queries 'after' object:

```
GET myindex-idx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"docType": "myDOcType"}}, 
        {"range": {
          "@date": {"gte": "2019-06-19T21:00:00", "lt": "2019-06-19T22:00:00"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "mybuckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 100, 
        "sources": [
          {"@date": {
            "date_histogram": {
              "field": "@date", 
              "interval": "hour", 
              "format": "date_hour"}
            }
          }, 
          {"field_1": {"terms": {"field": "field_1"}}}, 
          {"field_2": {"terms": {"field": "field_2"}}}, 
          {"field_3": {"terms": {"field": "field_3"}}}, 
          {"field_4": {"terms": {"field": "field_4"}}}, 
          {"field_5": {"terms": {"field": "field_5"}}}
        ],
      "after": {
        "@date": "2019-06-19T21",
        "field_1": 262,
        "field_2": 347,
        "field_3": 945,
        "field_4": 2258,
        "field_5": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This pages through the results, until the mybuckets returns empty

Comment: Could you also add an example that would help solve the problem in original question

Answer (score -2):

You can use the parameters from and size in your request. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html for more information. Your request would be something like this:

```
{
    "from" : 0, 
    "size" : 10,
    "aggs":{
        "group_by_state":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"poi_id"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "sum(price)":{
                    "sum":{
                        "field":"price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like from and size doesn't work to aggregation. I add a from:0 and size:1 to my aggregation request, and elasticsearch return three bucket.

Comment: OK i looked at it, the size parameter must be below your "field":"price" parameter. But pagination in aggregations seems not to be supported in elasticsearch. There are several stackoverflow threads e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776582/aggregation-sorting-pagination-in-elastic-search - it seems that in the actual es versions its the same...

Comment: Pagination doesn't work in aggregations. Read https://discuss.elastic.co/t/pagination-in-aggregation/79423/2?u=shankar_daruga