# Elasticsearch Aggregation Pagination

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, aggregate, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.4

Is there any way to do pagination using Elastic search with aggregation? 
the elasticsearch version is 2.3.
This is the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "clientMac": "88:"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "clientMac.rawData"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_client_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "event_timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "event_timestamp"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Paginating aggregation results is not available in ES - [Paging support for aggregations](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregation + sorting +pagination in elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776582/aggregation-sorting-pagination-in-elastic-search)

Answer (score 1):

From elastic 5 you do have the ability by partitioning the buckets of terms aggregation. You can read about it here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions