# Elasticsearch distinct records in order with pagination

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I get records after aggregation on a terms field in order with pagination. So far I have this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "user_id.keyword": [
              "user@domain.com"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "creation_time": {
              "gte": "2019-02-04T19:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2019-05-04T19:00:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "operation": "*sol*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "object_id": "*sol*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "user_id": "*sol*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "user_type": "*sol*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "client_ip": "*sol*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "country": "*sol*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "workload": "*sol*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "user_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country.keyword",
        "include": ".*United.*"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "creation_time": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776582/aggregation-sorting-pagination-in-elastic-search) and some people say its possible by using composite aggregations or by using partitions. But I am not sure how I can actually achieve this.

I also looked into bucket_sort but I cant seem to get it to work:

```
"my_bucket_sort": {
      "bucket_sort": {
        "sort": [
          {
            "user_ids": {
              "order": "desc"
            }
          }
        ],
        "size": 3
      }
    }
```

I am a noob at this. Kindly help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the field is country, and presumably doesn't have a high cardinality, you could set `size` to be a sufficiently high number to return all countries in a single request

```
  "aggs": {
    "user_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country.keyword",
        "include": ".*United.*",
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
```

Or alternatively, for a high cardinality field, you could filter the aggregation first, and then use partitioning to page through the values

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user_ids": {
      "filter": {
        "wildcard" : { "country" : ".*United.*" }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "countries": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "country.keyword",
            "include": {
              "partition": 0,
              "num_partitions": 20
            },
            "size": 10000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where you would increase the value of `partition` with each query you send up to 19

See the [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions) for further details

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to fix the number of buckets in partition? Say I want to paginate 10 buckets i.e. key values in a bucket, is there a way to do that?

Comment: The `size: 10000` parameter determines that. You'd need to make sure that `size` * `num_partitions` is less than the total number of unique values you have for the field. The linked elastic documentation recommends running a `cardinality` query first (which can then be used to determine the number of partitions you need)

Comment: Yeah I was looking into the documentation and cardinality aggregation as well. Can you kindly tell me how I would add cardinality aggregation in above query?

Comment: It wouldn't, it would need to go in a separate query. You'd then parse the response to get the number of unique values, then using that pick an appropriate number for `num_partitions` (assuming `size` would be constant)