# sql to es : get limit page and order result on agg

Tags: elasticsearch

```sql
SELECT
    max( timestamp ) AS first_time,
    min( timestamp ) AS last_time,
    src_ip,
    threat_target ,
    count(*) as count
FROM
    traffic 
GROUP BY
    src_ip,
    threat_target

ORDER BY
  first_time desc

LIMIT 0 ,10
```

I want to get this result, but I don't know how to get `limit size` and where to use `sort`

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "src_ip": {
      "aggregations": {
        "threat_target": {
          "aggregations": {
            "last_time": {
              "max": {
                "field": "`timestamp`"
              }
            },
            "first_time": {
              "min": {
                "field": "`timestamp`"
              }
            }
          },
          "terms": {
            "field": "threat_target.keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "terms": {
        "field": "src_ip.keyword"
      }
   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add mapping of your index.

Answer (score 0):

1. Aggregation Pagination is generally not supported in Elastic Search, however, composite aggregation provides a way to paginate your aggregation.

> Unlike the other multi-bucket aggregation the composite aggregation can be used to paginate all buckets from a multi-level aggregation efficiently.

Excerpt from [Composite-Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) ES Docs.

*CHECK:*  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776582/aggregation-sorting-pagination-in-elastic-search)

2. Except "ORDER BY first_time desc", below query should run fine for you. I don't think ordering on any fields other than the grouping fields (src_ip,
   threat_target) is possible.

   ```
    GET traffic/_search
    {
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
    "my_bucket": {
    "composite": {
    "size": 2,  //<=========== PAGE SIZE
    /*"after":{   // <========== INCLUDE THIS FROM Second request onwards, passing after_key of the last output here for next page
      "src_ip" : "1.2.3.5",
      "threat_target" : "T3"
    },*/
    "sources": [
      {

        "src_ip": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "source_ip",
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "threat_target": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "threat_target"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    },
   "aggs": {
    "first_time": {
      "max": {
        "field": "first_time"
      }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
   ```