# Elasticsearch - get all nested objects of all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's imagine Elasticsearch index where each document represents a country. Country has `cities` field, which is defined as `nested`.

Sample mapping (simplified for brevity of this example):

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      } 
    },
    "cities": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
        // other properties are omitted for brevity
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The documents which I'm inserting to the index look like this:

```
{
  "name": "Slovakia",
  "cities": [
    {
      "name": "Bratislava"
    },
    {
      "name": "Zilina"
    },
    ...
  ]
}

{
  "name": "Czech Republic",
  "cities": [
    {
      "name": "Praha"
    },
    {
      "name": "Brno"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to compose a query which returns all cities (over all countries) and supports sorting & pagination? In response, I'd like to have the complete nested objects + some fields of the parent object (so that I can display which country the city belongs to).

The first returned page (response) would contain 10 cities from Czech Republic, the second page would contain 10 cities where four of them are (the last ones) from Czech Republic and six are from Slovakia.

I was looking into [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html), but I don't know how add country name to `sources`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "nested_aggs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "cities"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_name": {
          "composite": {
            "sources": [
              {
                "cityName": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "cities.name.keyword",
                    "order": "asc"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to compose such query without modifying the Elasticsearch mapping?

Answer (score 0):

#### All members of composite aggregations need to be defined under the same context — you cannot intermix `nested` and non-nested contexts.

The easiest option would be to first aggregate on the countries and then on the cities:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_country": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_cities": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "cities"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_cities": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "cities.name.keyword",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

#### If you do have the option of changing the mapping, you can leverage the [`include_in_root` feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-params) which'll enable you to perform composite aggs such as:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_name": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "countryName": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "name.keyword",
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "cityName": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "cities.name.keyword",
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which can be easily [paginated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination).

Here's what the result would look like:

```json
...
"aggregations" : {
  "by_name" : {
    "after_key" : {
      "countryName" : "Slovakia",
      "cityName" : "Zilina"
    },
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : {
          "countryName" : "Czech Republic",
          "cityName" : "Brno"
        },
        "doc_count" : 1
      },
      {
        "key" : {
          "countryName" : "Czech Republic",
          "cityName" : "Praha"
        },
        "doc_count" : 1
      },
      {
        "key" : {
          "countryName" : "Slovakia",
          "cityName" : "Bratislava"
        },
        "doc_count" : 1
      },
      {
        "key" : {
          "countryName" : "Slovakia",
          "cityName" : "Zilina"
        },
        "doc_count" : 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately include_in_root doesn't help due to arrays flattening  - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects.

It works in this minimalistic use-case where we have only city name. It stops working (returns many invalid object combinations) as soon as we add another nested property to the sources, e.g. city ID.

Comment: True but your question did not mention that you'd be using more than just the city names  :) You can always go with my 1st suggestion — a combination of `terms`.

Comment: The 1st suggestion makes the pagination tricky. Let's say I want to get only 10 items (cities). In this case, I need to specify 10 as size of `by_country` aggregation and 10 as size of `by_cities` aggregation. As a result, I may get up to 100 results (cities) from which I want to display only 10. Also using this example with showing only 10 cities, I have no idea how to compose query like "Give me page #20".

Comment: I hear you. But frankly, aggregation results were never meant to be paginated. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27779382/8160318), I'd say it's best to aggregate all the cities applicable to any given query and handle the pagination in a cached middleware or on the client side... There's no "clean" answer to what you're after :)

Comment: I was afraid that there's no reasonable solution for this problem. Thanks for your input Joe!